# Injecting a Service into root Module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Im attemping to inject a service into the root module of my angular 2 application.

The service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    loggedIn : boolean = false;
    username : string = "Test";
    password : string = "";

    constructor( ) {

    }

    login ( username : string, password : string ) {
        this.loggedIn = true;
        return this.loggedIn;
    }

    logout ( ) {
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }

    getUsername ( ) {
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

Its obviously quite simple at the moment but im just trying to get it working

Im then trying to declare it as a provider in my root module, and then ive got it in the bootstrap collection of the decorator aswell:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';

import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { NavbarModule } from './navbar/navbar.module';

import { UserService } from './services/user.service'; 

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing, NavbarModule, UserModule, LoginModule],
  providers:    [ appRoutingProviders, UserService ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent, UserService ]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

I then attempt to use this service in appComponent like so

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { UserService } from './services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  providers: [ UserService ],
  templateUrl: './app.template.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor ( private userService: UserService ) {
        console.log( userService.getUsername() );
    }
}
```

I then get this error when I run the app

```
Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)
```

Any ideas on why this wouldn't work? Ive tried so many implementations

Comment: try removing the `providers` array in AppComponent. also you need to include `UserService` in bootstrap array in AppModule

Comment: Removing the providers array results in the same error. Also I already include UserService in the bootstrap array? => bootstrap:    [ AppComponent, UserService ] @candidJ

Answer (score 1):

Remove the service from the `bootstrap` section. Putting it in the `providers` section will suffice to make the service available as a singleton.
Also remove it from any `@Component()` decorators.

Comment: ok so removing it from the bootstrap array yields the same error. I also removed it from all component decorators and same again. I feel like I'm missing something here as this is the exact implementation I see used in all the material I have read

Comment: Weird. You should only have it in the providers section of @NgModule. I have only encountered that error when I tried to extend an injectable class. But it doesn't seem you're trying to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html#!#sts=Angular%20Modules%20(NgModules)%20have%20landed%20in%20Angular%20RC5!) 
the usage of `providers` array in component should be prohibited and it will be removed in next rc.

```
 @Component({ 
 selector: 'app',   
 templateUrl: './app.template.html'  //<-- removed providers array
 })
```

Including your services in `app.module`'s providers array will declare them globally (which you have already done) as pointed out in [providers section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#providers)
make the following changes :

```
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent]` //<---UserService  removed
```

make sure you are importing services from right directory.